# Convert this SQL to Doctrine Query Language (DQL)

Tags: doctrine-orm

I got following SQL query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM payment_schedule a, (
    SELECT loan_application_id, MAX(due_date) max_date
    FROM payment_schedule
    WHERE payment_type_id <> 3
    GROUP BY 1
) AS b
WHERE a.loan_application_id = b.loan_application_id
AND a.due_date = b.max_date
```

I want to convert this to DQL, I tried the following

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    Loan\Entity\PaymentSchedule a, (
        SELECT
            IDENTITY(ps2.loanApplication), MAX(ps2.dueDate) max_date
        FROM
            Loan\Entity\PaymentSchedule ps2
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS b
WHERE IDENTITY(a.loanApplication) = IDENTITY(b.loanApplication)
AND a.dueDate = b.max_date
```

This does not work, how do i construct such query in DQL ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? What error do you get?

Comment: It would help if you would post the error message you are getting. What I see from here is that a.* seems strange in DQL (you usually just write SELECT a) and MAX and IDENTITY might not be supported functions unless they added them recently, because last time I tried MAX it didn't know it.

Comment: I would also suggest using [the doctrine `QueryBuilder`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) for such a query...

Comment: In the documentation [you can read that `MAX` is not allowed](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#aggregate-functions) as @Tom already mentioned in the comment. `IDENTITY` is supported though...